# How are .pop and .index being used here?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a piece of code that I don't understand, I would appreciate it if someone could help me out.

```
list1 = [48, 33, 46, 46, 87, 11, 50, 99, 65, 87]    
list2 = [48, 33, 46]    
duplicates = [list1.pop(list1.index(i)) for i in list1 if i in list2]
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe your code does not meet your requirements:

You want to find which elements in `list1` are also in `list2`. The result should be `[48, 33, 46]`, but your result is `[48, 46]`.

This is because after it finds `48` as a duplicate, `48` is deleted from `list1`. During this process, the index of `33` changes from `1` to `0`. This means that the `for` can not iterate over this element, as now it wants to iterate from index `1`. So `33` is missed.

The correct code is:

```
list1 = [48, 33, 46, 46, 87, 11, 50, 99, 65, 87]
list2 = [48, 33, 46]
# duplicates = [list1.pop(list1.index(i)) for i in list1 if i in list2]
duplicates = list(set([i for i in list1 if i in list2]))
print duplicates
```

And the main thing here is a python list comprehension.

Explain new code logic:

```
1. iterate 1st element of `list1` and find it in `list2`, so pick it.
2. repeat step 1
3. finally you get [48, 33, 46, 46], use `set` to change to [48, 33, 46], 
   and use `list` to chanage back to list
```

Your old code logic:

```
1. iterate 1st element of `list1` and find it in `list2`, so pick it.
2. after pick it, you get the index of 1st element, then pop it 
   (delete it from `list1` and return the element)
    so for this iterate, you get `48`
3. then you want to iterate 2rd element of `list1`, that supposed to be `33`;
   however, during the process of step2, you delete the `48`, so `33` becomes
   the 1st element, nolonger the 2rd element, so when you iterate, you missed
   the `33` & directly iterate to the `46`
4. for these not in `list2`, will not be handled.
```

Answer (score 1):

Walk through it step by step, and it might make sense:

`for i in list1 if i in list2` should make sense; it's the equivalent of

```
for i in list1:
    if i in list2:
        ...
```

`list1.index(i)` gets the index of `i` (each element in `list1` that is found in `list2`), and finally `list1.pop` removes the item at that index from list1